# Elements living in the conjugacy class and in the centralizer of an $m$-cycle in $A_m$

Tags: gr.group-theory, nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, finite-groups

Let $m>1$ be an odd natural number, $x$ a $m$-cycle in $A_m$, the alternating group in $m$ letters, $C$ the conjugacy class of $x$ in $A_m$.

Question: How can I describe the elements in the set $\{ j \mid x^j \in C\}$ in terms of $m$?

For instance, if $C^\prime$ is the conjugacy class of $x$ in $S_m$, the symmetric group in $m$ letters, then
$$
\{ j \mid x^j \in C\} = \{ j \mid (j,m)=1 \},
$$ where $(j,m)$ is the greatest common divisor of $j$ and $m$. But in $A_m$, $C^\prime$ splits in two conjugacy classes of $A_m$ of the same size: $C$ and the conjugacy class of $(1 2)\times(1 2)$ in $A_m$.

Thank you in advance. Fernando.

Comment: Retagged to add nt, co, and finite-groups based on tags of similar questions. 

Answer (score 6):

The set is the quadratic residues when $m$ is prime, but usually not when $m$ is composite. For example,  $(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)$ is conjugate to $(0,2,4,6,8,1,3,5,7)$ in $A_9$ even though $2$ is not a square mod $9$, so there is no additional condition beyond $(j,9)=1$.

For $m$ odd, the sign of the permutation on $\mathbb Z/ m\mathbb Z$ of multiplication by $j$ is the [Jacobi symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_symbol) $\big(\frac jm\big)$. (This perspective on the Jacobi symbol is natural from one of Gauss's proofs of quadratic reciprocity, but it's also [theorem 1 here](http://www.math.us.edu.pl/%7Eszyjewski/Preprints/Zolotarew.pdf). Also see [Zolotarev's lemma](https://planetmath.org/zolotarevslemma).) Since there are two conjugacy classes of $m$-cycles in  $A_m$, $\big(\frac jm\big)=+1$ iff $x$ is conjugate to $x^j$ in $A_m$.

Comment: The link to `math.us.edu.pl` seems to be broken. I'm also unable to find any snapshot saved on the Wayback Machine.

Comment: @TheAmplitwist, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16361/elements-living-in-the-conjugacy-class-and-in-the-centralizer-of-an-m-cycle-in#comment1176491_16389), based on the URL, it might be [Szyjewski - Zolotarev's proof of Gauss reciprocity and Jacobi symbols](http://www.math.bas.bg/serdica/2011/2011-251-260.pdf), whose Theorem 1 does indeed seem to state the desired claim.

Comment: @LSpice Thanks! You're probably right, that must be the article that was meant.